# Can I take out L2 resonators with L1 XMP bursters?

Tags: ingress

I'm a Level 1 user. Can I destroy L2 resonators with L1 XMP bursters?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A L2 resonator is 1500 XM.

A L1 burster can make at most 150 XM damage (if you're exactly on the resonator as mentioned by BanditoBunny).

You will need at least 10 bursters to destroy 1 L2 resonator.

[Here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/96672/18551) you will find the different levels of bursters and resonators.

Comment: 150 at 0 distance