# What does it take to bring down a L5 Resonator If i'm only L2?

Tags: ingress

I'm at Level 2 on Ingress. Can I take down a portal that is full of L4 resonators and has ONE L5 resonator? If so, approximately what will it take?

I have about 50 L1 XMP bursters and 14 L2 XMP bursters.

There is [this information](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/96672/8216) about how much damage the XMP bursters do, but I don't think it shows how resistant the Resonators are.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quick answer: not with that inventory. But generally you might.
The important thing to know is that when you see 1% on the scanner as a damage number, that is rounded up to the nearest percent. The actual damage however will be lower than 1%. I've stood ON a level 5 resonator that showed around 20% health remaining and was the only resonator left on a portal. There I fired 15 level 1 XMP Bursters, I had 30 total. Some even showed Critical 1% instead of just 1%. However upon review of the portal at the half-way mark, the health level had not moved perceptively from about 20%, and it had no shields. I was level 3, but out of all level 3 and level 2 XMP Bursters.

Also your linked question with a chart and a table does show Resonator health levels at different levels in the bottom table.

So assuming they're full, 7 level 4 Resonators are 7*2500 = 17500, +3000 = 20500 for the level 5 resonator. You're armed with a hopeful 14 * 300 + 50 * 150 = 11700. Due to damage fall off at a distance you can't expect a near doubling of damage done to the non-proximate resonators.

Answer (score 7):

As dlamblin pointed out, your inventory is insufficient to do the job. Ignoring inventory issues, factors that come into play when attacking much higher level resonators as a low level player:

**XM storage**: Since your storage is less, the retaliation hits from high level enemy portals will quickly drain all your energy. Once its all gone, scanner gets disabled and you have to run around till it is recharged.
**Cellphone battery**: Yes, this is an important factor - because it can take forever to use small nukes & repeatedly collect XM.
**Time**: Similar to battery issues, don't play hitman when you need to leave soon. I've attacked an L6 portal (with some L7 resonators) as an L3, it took 30mins+ and ~ 60-70% of the battery.
**XMP levels**: Obviously, if you have a mass stock of L1 but are out of L2s, it takes far more effort.

I am assuming here that you are attacking fully charged resonators - of course, if you wait for decay and hit them right before expiring, then even L8 res could be destroyed easily.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers give useful advice, but it might be useful to add in a real life example.

Yesterday my wife and I (both level 2 players) captured two portals each of which had 4 level 4 and 4 level 3 fully charged resonators. It took the two of us about 47 level 2 XMPs to capture both portals (it could have been a few more as we hacked a few friendly portals in the middle.)

The first portal had all resonators very close to the portal; I hit it until my scanner was disabled then went off to recharge while my wife finished it off. After we were both back to 100% XM we hit the second one simultaneously; the resonators were widely spread so we pretty much had to hit them individually but damage from the portal was much less. Fortunately there were plenty other portals within a couple of hundred metres so XM wasn't a problem.

According to the COMM log it was 37 minutes from when we destroyed the first resonator until we finished creating the last field, so probably about 40-45 minutes total. if there hadn't been two of us I think battery life would have been the limiting factor, as it was both our phones were nearly drained.

Answer (score -1):

If you're at a lower level, the best way to go around them would be to wait them out and then give the final damage-dealing blow.