# How many XMP bursters do I need to take over a L1 portal?

Tags: ingress

I'm a new player to Ingress, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to take over a L1 portal. Let's say that the enemy has a L1 portal, with a few L2-L3 resonators, but for the most part, everything is L1. I'm looking for a few things specifically, such as:

1. How many bursters should I get? Assume full health.
2. What point should I aim for? The center?
3. If I destroy one of the resonators, can I replace it with my own, or does the entire thing need to be destroyed before I can do that?
4. How close do I actually need to be to the aimpoint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Answer to 3. : You'll have to destroy all the resonators before adding new ones.

Answer to 1./2./4. : If you're L1, you'll need a lot of bursters to destroy the portal. A XMP Burtster L1 can make 150 points damage when you stand on the resonator.

A L1 resonator health is 1000 points, so for each L1 resonator you'll need 6-7 bursters.

A L2 resonator health is 1500 points, so for each L2 resonator you'll need 10 bursters.

A L3 resonator health is 2000 points, so for each L3 resonator you'll need 13-14 bursters.

[source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/96672/18551)

BUT, if the portal is correctly protected with shields, (4 very rare shields, each one eat 10% of damages), they will **reduce damages by 40%**... so you'll need A LOT of bursters and time to destroy the complete portal...

And during the attack, owners can restore health of portal... The best solution would be to go there with many friends fully equiped :)

EDIT:
I found an [attack simulator](http://ipas.graphracer.com/) that will help you to predict how many bursters you will need to destroy a portal.

Comment: This really helps a lot... I just need to get a dozen or so bursters, take some down. Most of my intended target is only half strength, so it should be easy enough... Hmmmm... Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure about shields? I haven't seen any precise information about shield effects.

Comment: Shield behavior got changed some time ago, but I'm not sure how they work now. And the attack simulator is actually written by a fellow Ingress player in my area ;)

Comment: @Sentry : yes, shields behaviour change almost every week :s . You can thanks the attack simulator author, this is a very usefull tool, especially for low level players.

Comment: @CédricJulien you're welcome! - "The Author" ;-)

Comment: The simulator seems to be flawed. I set up two identical portals each with only three level 5 resonators in the same places. I common shield. Attacking in the same pattern. Using L1 xmps it took 143 of them to take it down. Using L2 xmps it took 356 of them on one try , 49 on another try. L3 xmps took 50. L4 - 25.